# Adding data to table dynamically:data updated is not getting reflected only the row get added

Tags: angularjs

```
<html ng-controller='myctrl'>
    <head>Student creation</head>
    <table border=1 width="100%">
        <tr style=background-color:lightblue>
        <th>username</th>
        <th>password</th>
        <th>department</th>
        <th>action</th>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat=" student in students" >
        <td>{{student.username}}</td>
        <td>{{student.password}}</td>
        <td>{{student.department}}</td>

        <td style=text-align:center> 
        <a href="/home/android/student/client/edit.html">Edit</a>&nbsp
        <a  onclick="calldeletefun()">delete</a>
        <script>
        function calldeletefun() {
            if (confirm("Do you want to delete student <<student name>>?") == true) {
                x = "you pressed ok";
            } else
                x = "you pressed cancel";
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
        }
        </script>
        &nbsp<a href="">marks</a>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <head>Student Edit/Add</head>
    <br><br>
    <body style=text-align:center>
        <form role="form" ng-submit="addRow()">
            <div>Studentname:
            <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="username"  style=border-color:blue ><br><br></div>
            <div>Password:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
            <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password"  style=border-color:blue><br><br></div>
            <div>Department:
            <input type="text1" name="department" ng-model="department"  style=border-color:blue><br><br></div>
            <div><input type="submit"  value="submit" style="color:white; background-color:green" >
            <input type ="submit" style="background-color:red; color:white" value="cancel"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Adding data to table dynamically:
On submitting the form only new row get added but data's given is not getting updated,Following is my controller code

```
    var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute'])

    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'table.html'

        })
        .when('/table1',
            {
            templateUrl : 'table.html'
        })

        .otherwise({
            redirectTo : '/'
        });
    });

 app.controller('myctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.students = [{
            'username' : 'user1',
            'password' : 'user1',
            'department' : 'cse'
        }, {
            'username' : 'user2',
            'password' : 'user2',
            'department' : 'IT'
        }, ];

    $scope.addRow = function () {

        $scope.students.push({
            username : $scope.username,
            'password' : $scope.password,
            'department' : $scope.department
        });
        $scope.username = "";
        $scope.password = "";
        $scope.department = "";
    };

 });
```

What went wrong here ? Can any please debug the code.

Comment: Your code is a mess... try to indent correctly HTML and JS: it's really hard to read

Comment: And there are a lot of HTML errors: `<head>` duplicated, `<body>` not closed, `<script>` inside a table...

Answer (score 0):

put ng-app in your HTML tag like

```
<html ng-app='myapp' ng-controller='myctrl'>
```

Remove ng-submit from form tag and put ng-click ="addRow()" on button.

Put return false in addRow function of your controller.

Let me know if this works for you.

The row is not getting added to the table because of the form is getting submitted i.e page is refreshing..

Answer (score 0):

See the working snippet I have added; the problem is with your html.

Maybe this will help you:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myctrl', function($scope) {
$scope.students=[{'username':'user1','password':'user1','department':'cse'},
{'username':'user2','password':'user2','department':'IT'},];


$scope.addRow=function()
{

$scope.students.push({username:$scope.username,'password':$scope.password,'department':$scope.department});
$scope.username="";
$scope.password="";
$scope.department="";
};
  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myctrl">
  
<table border=1 width="100%">
<tr style=background-color:lightblue>
<th>username</th>
<th>password</th>
<th>department</th>
<th>action</th>
</tr>

<tr ng-repeat=" student in students" >
<td>{{student.username}}</td>
<td>{{student.password}}</td>
<td>{{student.department}}</td>

<td style=text-align:center> 
<a href="/home/android/student/client/edit.html">Edit</a>&nbsp
<a  onclick="calldeletefun()">delete</a>
<script>
function calldeletefun()
{
if(confirm("Do you want to delete student <<student name>>?")==true)
{
x="you pressed ok";
}
else
x="you pressed cancel";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
}
</script>
&nbsp<a href="">marks</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<p id="demo"></p>
<h3>Student Edit/Add</h3>
<form role="form" ng-submit="addRow()">
<div>Studentname:
<input type="text" name="username" ng-model="username"  style=border-color:blue ><br><br></div>
<div>Password:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
<input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password"  style=border-color:blue><br><br></div>
<div>Department:
<input type="text1" name="department" ng-model="department"  style=border-color:blue><br><br></div>
<div><input type="submit"  value="submit" style="color:white; background-color:green" >
<input type ="submit" style="background-color:red; color:white" value="cancel"></div>
</form>
</div>
```